# Why is the transparent cornea not displaying the iris underneath?

Tags: texturing

The reflection just seems to be a nature scene. I had copied and pasted this eyeball from another project of mine, but the settings seem to be different.

I am trying to display the red iris underneath, if that makes sense. Not sure where the nature scene is coming from.

[image: cornea with transparency]

[image: red iris with map]

Comment: The 'nature scene' you're seeing is a reflection of the built-in HDRI in Blender's Eevee preview mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are in preview mode. If you use rendered view mode (in cycles) you would be able to see it.

You can preview alpha transparency in EEVEE or in preview mode by changing the `Blend Mode` in the material settings :

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Also, I think it would be better to use a Transparent shader instead of a Principled BSDF shader with `transmission` set to 1 in the cornea material.

**EDIT**

As @Blunder says in the comments, Screen Space Refractions is better if you need to have more accurate refractions, it will costs you a little bit of performance and in the case of something as thin as a cornea, you may not see a lot of difference but here is how you activate it :

You need to check `Screen Space Refractions` in the material settings

[image]

From there , you probably won't see any difference yet and it's because you'll also need to activate `Screen Space Reflections` and check `Refraction` in the `Render Settings` :

[image]

It will allow you to see some proper refraction :

[image]

You need to be aware, though, that Screen Space Refractions has some limitations and, according to the [official docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/screen_space_reflections.html#screen-space-reflections), Materials using Screen Space Refractions will not cast Screen Space Reflections.

There are also other limitations for the [Screen Space Reflecions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html#screen-space-reflections) and [Screen Space Refractions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html#screen-space-refraction) that you may want to take into account.

Comment: The answer is not quite correct. For transparency via the alpha mask, the answer is correct. But here the shader of the question uses *Transmission* and not *Alpha*. If *Transmission* is used you need to tick *Screen Space Refraction* in the material settings (first screenshot of this answer) and you need to enable *Screen Space Refractions* and *Screen Space Refractions > Refraction* in *Eevee* render settings to make it work in *Material Preview*. My bet is that the Eevee options are not enabled yet (the material was copied).

Comment: thank you both! You're right @Blunder this worked for me :D

Comment: @Blunder thanks for the precisions, you are right, indeed, `Alpha Blend` only gives alpha transparency and not refraction. But for something very thin like a cornea or windows panes, having accurate glass refractions would be a bit of overkill and you would barely notice the difference (that's why I suggested to replace the `Principled` shader with a `Transparent` shader). I edited my answer above to include your remarks.